# (AS3) cannot read JSON in Localhost(IIS)

Tags: json, actionscript-3, iis, localhost

I'm trying to get a JSON file loaded in AS3 while using Localhost(IIS).
If I am running the file locally it works perfectly fine.
But when I open the swf with Localhost, it just won't load the JSON file for no reason...
the Permissions should be given, since I am able to load images from the same folder...
any idea?

swf code

```
import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;
var textytext:TextField=new TextField()
addChild(textytext)
var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("TESTJSON.json");
var myLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onload);
myLoader.load(myRequest);
var myData:Object
function onload(evt:Event):void
{
    textytext.text="nichts"
    myData= JSON.decode(myLoader.data);
    textytext.text=String(myData.ReadMePlease)
}
```

and the JSON file

```
{
"ReadMePlease":"Awww yeah"
}
```

Comment: 1. try the full url, for example: http:// localhost/TESTJSON.json (without space), 2. add IOError and SecurityError event listeners to the URLLoader and trace messages if they exists

Comment: tried both...got the following error

Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://localhost/testsite/TESTJSON.json
 at jsontry_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

Comment: Now you check this url in your browser, because flash says that this url is invalid.

Comment: FOUND IT! after some more research, i found out i had to add a MIME type for my JSON file in the IIS.

thank you for getting me to the core problem :) (this tutorial helped me a lot at my problem) http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap

Answer (score 0):

try always allow at Flash Global Settigns (http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html)
Also you can set [allowdomain](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Security.html)